# Is it possible to create local, disposable CVS repositories in the context of a unit test?

Tags: git, unit-testing, cvs

I have some code that interacts with a CVS repository that is a frequent source of software defects, probably because it has no test coverage whatsoever.

The code *would* have test coverage if my tests could create a dummy CVS repository, interact with it, make assertions, and then discard the dummy CVS repository.  This would all happen inside of the unit-test folder, rather than in one of the system folders.  (This whole thing is incredibly easy in Git, and may actually be an argument in favor of migrating to Git.)

Has anyone done this kind of thing?  Does anyone know how?  Will I be forced to run my unit tests as `root`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly possible. In another technology, on another OS, we did it on our opensource project 'git-tfs'.

We use the libgit2 library and it should exist a binding for your language. But you still can use the git command line even if it could be more painful.

Perhaps you will also need your own DSL to easy your git repository creation.

And, no, you don't need root rights if you create your repositories in a folder where you have write right.

Comment: Yes, this is easy to do with git.  My question is: can it be done with CVS.

Comment: Oups, I don't know why I didn't understand that you were asking for cvs, and not git. Perhaps because I was browsing the git tag... I can't help you on the subject :-( but it's mostly unlikely because cvs is centralised and need a server...